# JSDoc - Is reusing type definitions from other modules an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Imagine this project structure:

```
api/
  activity/
    index.js
    activity.d.js <-- JSDOC Type Definitions

contexts/
  activity/
    ActivityContext.jsx 
    ActivityContext.d.js <-- JSDOC Type Definitions
```

In *api/activity/activity.d.js* I have the type definition "**A**" and I wanna reuse it in *context/activity/ActivityContext.jsx*.

There are two options:

1. Copying and pasting the specific type definition of *api/activity/activity.d.js* inside *contexts/activity/ActivityContext.d.js*.
2. Or (the one I prefer) importing *api/activity/activity.d.js* inside *contexts/activity/ActivityContext.jsx*.

**Is it considered an anti-pattern to reuse types from other modules in JSDOC?**

Comment: Going outside of JSDoc for a moment, this is a classic example where you'd end up extracting some entities into a "shared" or "global" namespace, and then import those both in `api/` and `contexts/`. You don't need to have 1:1 matching of source files and their corresponding type files.

Comment: What are you using jsdoc for? Autocompletion, documentation generation, typechecking?

Comment: No, it's certainly not an antipattern to reuse code; quite on the contrary duplicated code is the antipattern. Unless these are really totally separate modules that just accidentally use objects of the same shape and may evolve differently - but in that case you'd also name the types differently.

Comment: @Bergi documentation generation and for intellisense purposes

Comment: BTW I think I will go with what @jakub.g said, declaring some definitions in a global module, rather than in a named context, which may be confusing.

Comment: @VictorMolina For documentation, if you mean the same thing and also want to generate a link to a single shared definition, you definitely should reuse (reference) the type from the other module (or a shared global module - might not matter as long as the structure makes sense) instead of copying the code